# GIt push dry run and git pull works, but not git push

Tags: git, gitolite

In the server that I am currently working on, I checkout a branch that I tried to modify. At the moment I am trying to push my change to thisbranch.

After checkout the branch (git checkout myfeature), to check that I am in the correct branch, I do the following.

```
workdir>git branch
* myfeature
  master
```

and after I made a local change, commit it (git commit -m) and try to push it with first dry-run

```
workdir>git push --dry-run
To http://myurl/myrepo.git
   64344f9c4..54efeffb6  myfeature -> myfeature
```

to check the latest status I do the following

```
workdir>git status
On branch myfeature
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/myfeature' by 1 commit.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
```

however when I tried to push it, I kept getting this error

```
workdir>git push
Enumerating objects: 9, done. Counting objects: 100% (9/9), done. Delta compression using up to 8 threads Compressing objects: 100% (5/5), done. Writing objects: 100% (5/5), 542 bytes |
    67.00 KiB/s, done. 
    Total 5 (delta 4), reused 0 (delta 0) 

remote: WARNING: Use of uninitialized value $repo in concatenation (.) or string at /home/gitolite/gitolite-source/src/lib/Gitolite/Conf/Load.pm line 239, 
<DATA> line 1. remote: remote: FATAL: invalid repo '' remote: error: hook declined to update refs/heads/myfeature To http://myurl/myrepo.git  ! [remote rejected]     
myfeature -> myfeature (hook declined)
```

I tried to check whether I have access using git pull and it works

```
git pull

Already up to date.
```

I noticed that the error is complaining that the repo is not set (invalid repo ''). However as I have set the remote origin (deleted it, and also tried to readd it) still it complained on the same issue

```
workdir>git config --get remote.origin.url
http://myurl/myrepo.git
```

This does not seem to be a permission error, as I managed to pull the code. 
The Origin and upstream is already set as well (hence I manage to pull).

How can I push to the above branch?

Comment: The problem is not on your side. This is a hook rejecting your push (`error: hook declined to update refs/heads/myfeature To http://myurl/myrepo.git  ! [remote rejected]     
myfeature -> myfeature (hook declined)`). Who's the administrator of this repo? You should see with them.

Comment: Looks like a bug in gitolite (it's failing to initialize a variable used by a hook) or one of the hooks being run on the remote end.

Comment: can you try again specifying repo and branch on git push and pull

Comment: workdir>git push -u origin myfeature throw me the same result @jo_

Comment: @RomainValeri yes I am currently looking at the code for gitolite in github where the error was thrown, but currently not finding any obvious mistake from my side

Comment: @sateayam I'd search the bug reports on Gitolite to see if it's a known issues (it could be fixed already), and if not, file a bug report.  Sitaram has been a great maintainer and I bet he can help track down what is going on pretty quickly.

Comment: yes, you are correct. I just went through the code, and even though the repo variable is correctly set in gitolite.conf, on the "push" command, the sanity check kicks in and at that point the repo var does not have any value. however, for pull, the repo is there. I will check their maling list to see if anyone notice a similar behaviour @JohnSzakmeister